Jetpack Compose StickyHeaders on the same line as an LazyColumn item
How can i can implement sticky headers like in Contacts?
I saw this implementation, but maybe there is a more concise solution?
My code below
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    groupedNames.forEach { (initial, namesForInitial) ->
        stickyHeader {
            Text(
                text = initial.toString(),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                maxLines = 1,
            )
        }
        items(namesForInitial) { name ->
            NameItem(name)
        }
    }
}


What particular problem are you facing while employing the solution you're referring to? Here is how you can provide MRE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
